# Drawing fields within a UML Class Diagram when generating from CSV

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I followed the example here:

https://jgraph.github.io/drawio-tools/tools/csv.html

To create a UML Class Diagram from CSV. All went well, however, there is no documentation or sample of how to create the fields.

While if you are creating as text, you can easily create fields, e.g.

```
Person
-name: String
-birthDate: Date
--
+getName(): String
+setName(String): void
+isBirthday(): boolean
```

My questions are:

- How can we create fields when creating a UML Diagram from CSV
- Can you create a UML diagram from text? With multiple classes and relationships?

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML at the ' label: 'part in the # control text at top of the import file where you see the ## and # text 
Use %columnName% per column as your variables